# Create a single horizontal stacked bar chart from pandas data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm looking to create a single horizontal stacked bar chart as an alternative to a pie chart to show percentages.

I'm pretty sure plot.barh will do the job (it creates multiple stacked bars in another piece of code I have). But here it doesn't stack the bars. How do I fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=pd.DataFrame(data={"R1":["Yes","Yes","Yes","No","No"]})
freq = data["R1"].value_counts(normalize=True)*100
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
freq.plot.barh(ax=ax,stacked=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stacking means putting several series of one dataframe on top of each other, so their values cumulate.
You have a single series only, with two values, which consequently are plotted in one bar series.

You could make a DataFrame out of your series, transform it so that `Yes` and `No` are two columns with one value each and then plot it the way you tried:

```
freq.to_frame().T.plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

[image]

---

to examine the difference:

```
freq

# Yes    60.0
# No     40.0
# Name: R1, dtype: float64

freq.to_frame().T

#      Yes    No
# R1  60.0  40.0
```

Comment: Ouch - it works, yes. But for some reason Matplotlib is putting that plot below the normal axis, so I'm getting two plots, with the correct one underneath a vanilla blank plot one with the default axes (I can't seem to add images to a comment, sorry). Never seen that before!

How do I fix that?

Comment: Impossible to say without the code. And as the principle of your question above is answered here, this new issue might be better placed in a new question.