# Python Matplotlib/Seaborn/Jupyter - Putting bar plot in wrong place?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm using the following in a Jupyter notebook, using the latest Anaconda update (including Matplotlib 3.1.1,)

Thanks to SpghttCd, I have the [code to do a stacked horizontal bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57850399/python-create-a-single-horizontal-stacked-bar-chart-from-pandas-data/57850469), but Seaborn puts it on a new plot below the default one.

How might I best fix this problem?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data=pd.DataFrame(data={"R1":["Yes","Yes","Yes","No","No"]})
freq = data["R1"].value_counts(normalize=True)*100
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
freq.to_frame().T.plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Remove `fig,ax = plt.subplots()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see two axes in Jupyter because you create a fresh one with `plt.subplots()` and pandas also creates another one.

If you need to reuse an existing axe, pass it to plotting method using `ax` switch:

```
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
freq.to_frame().T.plot.barh(stacked=True, ax=axe)
```

See pandas documentation for details, plotting method always exhibits an `ax` switch:

> `ax` : Matplotlib axis object, optional

If you accept pandas creates it for you, as @Bharath M suggested, just issue:

```
axe = freq.to_frame().T.plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

Then you will see an unique axes and you can access it trough the variable `axe`.